# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute') mat-checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-material

I'm trying to use some Angular Material Components such as mat-checkbox, but when I set a custom attribute, I get

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')

The code used is as it goes:

```
<li *ngFor="let instancia of tipo_maquina.instancias">
    <mat-checkbox 
     (change)="onCheckChange($event, $event.source, $event.checked)"
     [attr.typeid]="instancia.id">
      {{instancia.nombre}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</li>
```

```
onCheckChange(event: any, checkbox: MatCheckbox, isChecked: boolean){
    console.log("check event")
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('typeid'));
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you just log event.target? (PS: this looks like a code smell.. why do you need this?)

Comment: Better would be to forget using an attribute and just do onCheckChange($event, instancia.id)..?

Comment: @MikeOne it's returning undefined

Comment: That explains then. En just event? Anyway, I’d just go for my second comment to be honest.

Comment: @MikeOne oh my... you are absolutely right. I'm going to do that. Many thanks!

Comment: Cool. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `$event` should be `MatCheckboxChange` and it has 2 properties

```
    /** Change event object emitted by MatCheckbox. */
    export declare class MatCheckboxChange 
    {
        /** The source MatCheckbox of the event. */
        source: MatCheckbox;
        
       /** The new `checked` value of the checkbox. */
        checked: boolean;
    }
```

So target does not exist on `MatCheckboxChange` and you would get an error
**error TS2339: Property target' does not exist on type 'MatCheckboxChange'**.

As @MikeOne suggested, just pass `instancia.id` to the `onCheckChange($event, instancia.id)` method.